# Filter a Django ManyToManyField by a multiple intersection with another ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Suppose I have the following models

```
class Tag(models.Model):
  tag = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Entry(models.Model):
  ...
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='entries')
  ...

class Option(models.Model):
  ...
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='options')
```

How can I get a queryset of Option instances that have at least 2 tags present in the tags set of a given Entry instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
from django.db.models import Count

options = Option.objects.filter(tags__in=entry.tags.all())
options = options.annotate(tag_count=Count('tags'))
options = options.filter(tag_count__gte=2)
```